# Unique session using token JWT Angular Auth

Tags: angular, jwt

I have an idea to build a basic session auth app and it works, but i can login with the same user in two diferent browser.
Does anyone have an idea how to build an auth method to avoid `the double login?`
My app actualy use Angular version 5 and like backend Django Rest Framework,
this is my actual method auth **service.ts**:

```
private apiRoot = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/';
    islogedin: boolean;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    private setSession(authResult) {
      const token = authResult.token;
      const payload = <JWTPayload> jwtDecode(token);
      const expiresAt = moment.unix(payload.exp);

      localStorage.setItem('token', authResult.token);
      localStorage.setItem('expires_at', JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()));
    }

    get token(): string {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
      return this.http.post(
        this.apiRoot.concat('login/'),
        { username, password }
      ).pipe(
        tap(response => this.setSession(response)),
        shareReplay(),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package Simple JWT ([enter link description here](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt)).

There is a field in settings called **JTI_CLAIM**: 
The claim name that is used to store a token's unique identifier. This identifier is used to identify revoked tokens in the blacklist app. It may be necessary in some cases to use another claim besides the default "jti" claim to store such a value.